# Is there any scheduling technique in Android?

Tags: android, operating-system, scheduling, preemptive

I am a high school student who is curious about how stuffs in the technology world works. I've read a book about Android operating system, borrowed from my aunt months ago. And I've been wondering, is there any scheduling technique in Android? I am specifically curious about the processor time slicing or anything related with that, but not the memory resources. As an Android user, I am keen to know how the process works behind the screen more detail. Thank you in advance!

p/s: English is not my first language, so I want to apologize for any mistake. Thanks!

Edit: I want to know more about pre-emptive scheduling in Android. Also if you know good websites for me to read and understand, feel free to share me the link, I would be more that pleased to read it.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Also, SO permits only pepperoni, habaneros and chilli sauce as toppings.

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you for the comment! If i were to narrow it down, I would like to know more about the pre-emptive scheduling techniques in Android. Also, pineapple on pizza is very delicious, i think i should treat you some time.